# Why a movieclip or any other subcomponent become publically accessible when provided instance name?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Say i placed a movieclip inside a movieclip A_Mc ( representing ClassA) . Now if i place another movieclip ( without naming, and making sure that automatic instance naming is Off via the flash IDE ), everything runs fine. But when i provide an instance name say b_Mc , then it MUST be able to be publically accessible.

What is the logic behind this setup. Why while designing i cannot make a sub-movieclip which is private and inaccessible to others ?

Comment: If its on the display stack then it's always publicly accessible via `getChildAt()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this is just for simplicity sake. The Flash IDE is targeted at designers, so that might be very confusing if you started talking about public and private.

I can't think of any reason why you would want private graphics anyway. I can't see anything wrong with having access to all child graphics.

Answer (score 0):

The AS3 documentation states that any symbols placed on the stage are public. The reason for this is that there is no way to declare a stage instance as public or private from within the IDE Timeline. Therefore, the only case that allows for either public or private access is to use public. There are of course problems with all you stage members being public.

But from the point of view of adobe - they are trying to make the Flash IDE friendly to design and animation oriented users to whom the idea of public and private members is unfamiliar. So they do not provide a field to allow you to specify a member symbol name as private.

But a good workaround is to export the graphics as a class with no implementation, just public instances. Then add that to your implementation class as a private variable. Then add it to the stage of the implementation class, if that class is a display object. If you're here on StackOverflow, I think you're up to the challenge ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The Flash player can't put your instance into the variable the instance name points to unless it is public.  For more on this, check out http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html